# Salesforce show all cases based on criteria in visualforce

Tags: salesforce, case, visualforce, apex

All,

I am attempting to show all cases that meet certain criteria in salesforce using visual force page, then I would like to use that data in a gantt chart.  I do know much about coding, but trying based on user manuals.  This visualforce page comes back without any case information.

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >  
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlockButtons> 
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:PageBlockTable value="{!Case}" var="c">
                <apex:column value="{!c.Account}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!c.Number}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!c.Owner}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Install Date">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!a.Planned_Install_Date__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:PageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an apex controller class to get data from Salesforce to the visual force page. Something like this:

Visual Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" controller="MyCaseController">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >  
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlockButtons> 
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:PageBlockTable value="{!Cases}" var="c">
            <apex:column value="{!c.Accountid}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.CaseNumber}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.OwnerId }"/>
            </apex:PageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Controller:

```
public class MyCaseController {

    public list<Case> cases {get;set;}

    public MyCaseController(){
        cases  = [select id, accountid, CaseNumber, OwnerId from case];
    }
}
```

You should be able to accommodate the code to your needs.